# Weights + Conditioning circuit + Mixed martial arts

Tags: workout, muscle, bodybuilding, martial-arts, crossfit

I'm thinking of starting a regime, where I hit my local gym 3 hours a day 6 days a week. I  am 5'7" with a moderate build and I weigh 65kg. I'm wanting to build muscle and lose fat.

The first 1hr involves weight training, (working a different body part every day)

2nd hr a conditioning circuit of callisthenic exercises, battling ropes, kettle bell swings, bulgarian bags, deadlift clean and press squats etc (30 seconds on each 15 seconds rest between sets, 2mins rest between circuits).

3rd hour is my mixed martial arts class focusing on wrestling and padwork.

With the right diet, would this make me hit my goals? Or is this overwork and could result in my muscles cannibalising themselves? I really enjoy the mma and circuit work which is why I want to include them in my training.

Thanks

Ade+

Comment: I think that you should first start with not so intensive workouts and little by little climb up to the full-time regime.

Comment: What are your goals? the ability to workout 3 hrs x 6 days a week? Or is there a more focused goal like MMA champ, Mr Olympia, Movie Star?  It seems obsessive, outside of top end athletes ramping up.

Comment: How old are you?  What's your prior training?  Are you familiar with a condition called exertional rhabdomyolysis?  If not:  http://www.athleteinme.com/ArticleView.aspx?id=241

Answer (score 5):

### Sure...?

It could work if you have phenomenal recovery. If you've been doing an hour or two 6 days a week for a while and feel OK, feel free to add a third hour. If you're starting from zero, or from just MMA, or from four days a week training, I doubt your plan will work unless you build up to it very, very gradually.

### Some Concerns About Your Plan

1. You put deadlifts, cleans, presses and squats into "conditioning". Do you do CrossFit, or is this just a mistake? These are strength exercises that belong in the lifting category.
2. Is there a reason you're splitting your lifting into body parts? Are you doing a bodybuilding routine (arms, chest, back, legs) or a strength program (3x5, 5x5, singles, doubles)? Answers to [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3962/are-these-workout-routines-right-for-body-building/3963) talk about the distinction.
3. What's your current routine? Because 3 hours a day, six days a week, is a daunting workload for anyone. If you haven't ramped up to it, I would say you're headed for overtraining.
4. Are you planning on these three hours being consecutive?
5. Why is your conditioning an hour long? Glenn Pendlay (a well-respected Olympic lifting coach) recommends a lot, lot less for those training MMA--on the order of [10 minutes](http://www.pendlayforum.com/showthread.php?t=2516). Even CrossFitters, well-known for taking conditioning to an obscene, often unsustainable level, don't do an hour of conditioning a day unless they're a top-level Games contender.