# What is a good and tested body building programs for a beginner?

Tags: workout-routines, bodybuilding, strength-training

What would be a good body building program for a beginner? I have been searching the Internet and find a lot of programs but am not sure about the credibility of the people who have published these programs. For example, in the world of strength training, StrongLifts, Starting strength, and Bill Starr are all famous and very credible programs. What could be their equivalent in bodybuilding?

I am looking for reputable Programs that have passed the test of time and have been designed by reputable coaches. If the coach is maintaining a forum for the same that is even more welcome. Please do not post a program that works/worked for you. The Program should also be a beginner program which can explain gains for novice bodybuilders and be totally steroid free.

Comment: At the moment you are basically asking for a list, which is nearly always bad. It would be better if you'd rephrase your question and ask for things to look for in a body building program. It is very subjective to determine "popular" or "beginner". In its current form the question will likely be cluttered with links to third class Youtube videos (but a million views, which makes them popular). If you would rephrase it, it would have timeless value (unless there are radical changes to the idea of body building).

Comment: Have a look at the reasoning behind [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), even though your questions isn't specifically a shopping question.

Comment: Hmm.. thinking about editing it.. some how looks ok to me.. I mentioned I would like to see reputable programs and not tailor made programs by anyone. Let me see if I can further improve the question. Thanks for your suggestion :-)

Comment: If you want to get more specific answers, maybe post the programs you've already found and explain what you are missing in them.

Comment: My understanding is that the Reg Park beginner routine is very close to what you're asking for. It is described in [this answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/3963/1771).

Answer (score 8):

Body-building is an individual pursuit that requires specific understanding of the individual in question. A general beginner's course would be so simple as to be useless - there is no sense in writing a body-building guide for average height adult males under 60 kg; they have much more fundamental problems. Likewise, 120 kg average height females should not begin on a body-building course until they have somewhat normalised their weight through appropriate measures.

---

Here is my summary of the useful content that a course such as this would contain:
Eat well and get a decent base strength (should take 3-6 months for ca. 90% of adult population).

---

I suggest that you should follow a program such as Starting Strength until you have reached an intermediate level of strength. Once you have reached the intermediate stage you will have learnt enough about your own body to begin tailoring a specific body-building program that works for you. Then you can read non-beginner's body-building manuals and they will seem relevant to you.

There is no sense in a beginner's body-building program applicable to everyone. The beginning stage of body-building is a basic understanding of physical health.

Comment: ... The suspense!