# Is there name for this Rep Set?

Tags: bodybuilding, workout-types

I am exercising in this way:

-First i make one set of max weight i can lift like 15 kg(33 lbs) for 12 rep.Then i lower it to 12 kg and one more set and so on until my arms feel exhausted and i cant event lift 5 kg.

With this method my arms really burn and develop

Is there name for this workout and do you think it is a nice workout?

(I am beginner bodybuilder,no previous sports life)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called drop sets.

[Muscle And Fitness](http://www.muscleandfitness.com/workouts/workout-routines/gain-greater-mass-drop-sets)

> **WHAT ARE DROP SETS?**
>
> Drop sets are essentially a technique where you perform an exercise and then drop (reduce) the weight and continue for more reps until you reach failure. Called the ‘multi-poundage system’ this method was discovered in 1947 by Henry Atkins, who was the editor of Body Culture magazine.

Drop sets are good, but are more geared towards intermediate or advanced lifters. If you're truly a beginner, look for a beginner program that takes advantage of your lack of experience to get stronger faster. [This answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/3963/18977) gives you more insight on beginner workouts / how to get started in body building.